# How to set the DPI of an image before saving it?

Tags: image, image-processing, rust

With the following code, I'm changing the position of PNG images in a folder, then merging them with another image:

```
fn main() {
    let input_dir = "./input";
    let entries = fs::read_dir(input_dir).unwrap();
    let text_img = image::open("text.png").unwrap();

    for entry in entries {
        let path = entry.unwrap().path();

        if let Some("png") = path.extension().and_then(|s| s.to_str()) {
            let input_img = image::open(&path).unwrap();
            let mut shifted_img = visual_center(input_img);

            imageops::overlay(&mut shifted_img, &text_img, 0, 0);

            let output_format = ImageOutputFormat::Png;
            let output_path = format!("./output/{}", path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap());
            let mut output_file = std::fs::File::create(&output_path).unwrap();

            shifted_img
                .write_to(&mut output_file, output_format.with_density(300, 300))
                .unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

Before saving them, I want to set their DPI to 300. Right now, I'm getting this error:

> no method named `with_density` found for enum `ImageOutputFormat` in the current scope

Why is this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Because there is no such method?

Comment: I mean, why did you expect it to work? Where did you see there is such method?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I made a mistake; I misread some code on Github. What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: I have no idea. But [search for "density" on docs.rs](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/?search=density), it gives some interesting results. And make sure to post the answer here once you find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [`png`](https://crates.io/crates/png) crate, because it is not fully re-exported from [`image`](https://crates.io/search?q=image), however it [is a dependency](https://github.com/image-rs/image/blob/139420ddfcf5d4b937987a09769e5f201b7a2a29/Cargo.toml#L39) nevertheless.

Then you can write the metadata like so (this snippet uses a generated example image):

```rust
use std::{fs::File, io::BufWriter};

fn main() {
    let mut imgbuf = image::ImageBuffer::new(512, 512);

    // Generate a sample image.
    for (x, y, pixel) in imgbuf.enumerate_pixels_mut() {
        let r = (0.3 * x as f32) as u8;
        let b = (0.3 * y as f32) as u8;
        *pixel = image::Rgb([r, 0, b]);
    }

    let file = File::create("test.png").unwrap();
    let w = &mut BufWriter::new(file);

    let mut encoder = png::Encoder::new(w, 512, 512);
    encoder.set_color(png::ColorType::Rgb);
    encoder.set_depth(png::BitDepth::Eight);
    encoder.set_compression(png::Compression::Best);

    let mut writer = encoder.write_header().unwrap();

    let data = get_dpi_header_data(300);
    writer.write_chunk(png::chunk::pHYs, data.as_slice()).unwrap();

    writer.write_image_data(&imgbuf).unwrap();
}

/// Converts the given `dpi` value to the appropriate _pHYs_ chunk data.
/// 
/// Arguments:
/// 
/// * `dpi`: The **dots per inch** of the image.
/// 
/// Returns:
/// 
/// A [Vec<u8>] with the encoded chunk data.
fn get_dpi_header_data(dpi: u32) -> Vec<u8> {
    let dpm = 39.370079 * dpi as f32; // Convert from dots per inch to dots per meter.
    let rounded_dpm = dpm.round() as u32;

    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    data.extend_from_slice(&rounded_dpm.to_be_bytes()); // Pixels per unit in X-direction.
    data.extend_from_slice(&rounded_dpm.to_be_bytes()); // Pixels per unit in Y-direction.

    data.push(1); // Indicate that meters are used as unit.
    data
}
```

The relevant chunk is documented in the [PNG Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/png/) in [this section](https://www.w3.org/TR/png/#11pHYs).

P.S.: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/image-rs/image/issues/911) to make this more ergonomic in the future.

### Update because of OP comment

Here is the full code for the use-case in the question:

```rust
use std::{fs::File, io::BufWriter};

use image::{ImageBuffer, Pixel, imageops};

fn main() {
    let input_dir = "./input";
    let entries = std::fs::read_dir(input_dir).unwrap();
    let text_img = image::open("text.png").unwrap();

    for entry in entries {
        let path = entry.unwrap().path();

        if let Some("png") = path.extension().and_then(|s| s.to_str()) {
            let mut input_img = image::open(&path).unwrap();

            let input_img = image::open(&path).unwrap();
            let mut shifted_img = visual_center(input_img);

            imageops::overlay(&mut shifted_img, &text_img, 0, 0);

            let output_path = format!("./output/{}", path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap());
            let output_file = std::fs::File::create(&output_path).unwrap();

            save_png_with_dpi(output_file, &shifted_img.into_rgba8(), 300).unwrap();
        }
    }
}

/// Writes the PNG image data to the given `file` and assigns the given
/// `dpi` to the image.
/// 
/// Arguments:
/// 
/// * `file`: The file to which the image data is written.
/// * `imgbuf`: The [ImageBuffer] containing the unencoded image data.
/// * `dpi`: The **dots per inch** which will be assigned to the image.
/// 
/// Returns:
/// 
/// A [Result<(), std::io::Error>] indicating if the operation was successful.
fn save_png_with_dpi<P>(
    file: File,
    imgbuf: &ImageBuffer<P, Vec<u8>>,
    dpi: u32,
) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>
where
    P: Pixel<Subpixel = u8>,
{
    let w = &mut BufWriter::new(file);

    let mut encoder = png::Encoder::new(w, 512, 512);

    match <P as Pixel>::CHANNEL_COUNT {
        4 => encoder.set_color(png::ColorType::Rgba),
        3 => encoder.set_color(png::ColorType::Rgb),
        _ => {
            return Err(std::io::Error::new(
                std::io::ErrorKind::InvalidData,
                "Incorrect color channel count / format.",
            ))
        }
    }
    encoder.set_depth(png::BitDepth::Eight);
    encoder.set_compression(png::Compression::Best);

    let mut writer = encoder.write_header()?;

    let data = get_dpi_header_data(dpi);
    writer.write_chunk(png::chunk::pHYs, data.as_slice())?;

    writer.write_image_data(imgbuf)?;

    Ok(())
}

/// Converts the given `dpi` value to the appropriate _pHYs_ chunk data.
///
/// Arguments:
///
/// * `dpi`: The **dots per inch** of the image.
///
/// Returns:
///
/// A [Vec<u8>] with the encoded chunk data.
fn get_dpi_header_data(dpi: u32) -> Vec<u8> {
    let dpm = 39.370079 * dpi as f32; // Convert from dots per inch to dots per meter.
    let rounded_dpm = dpm.round() as u32;

    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    data.extend_from_slice(&rounded_dpm.to_be_bytes()); // Pixels per unit in X-direction.
    data.extend_from_slice(&rounded_dpm.to_be_bytes()); // Pixels per unit in Y-direction.

    data.push(1); // Indicate that meters are used as unit.
    data
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output is really strange, ha: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUMBb.png

Comment: Well my assumption was that someone with your reputation would be able to adapt this code snippet to their needs. Did you even read the code before running it? It literally says in the comment "Generate a sample image."...
However I updated my answer with a full code sample which should do what you want. I am not entirely sure though, because you did not include the `visual_center` function in your sample which is far from a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by the way.

Comment: Oh, yes, I read that part. But I forgot about it when I ran the code. Thanks for reminding me. And thanks again, as far as I know, there isn't another example like this on web.

Comment: Sorry, I have a question. The final image is composed of two merged images of 4500 x 5400, so I updated that in your code: `let mut encoder = png::Encoder::new(w, 4500, 5400);`. But I get this error: `"wrong data size, expected 72900000 got 97200000"`

Comment: Since it is exactly `4/3` of the expected value (e.g. `4500 * 5400 * 3 = 72900000`) it is almost certainly an issue with **RGB** vs **RGBA**. You could try `&shifted_img.into_rgb8()` instead?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I set `encoder.set_color(png::ColorType::Rgb);` and then used `&shifted_img.into_rgba8()` for the data. Obviously these values must match. I updated the code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! As a Rust beginner, this is quite difficult. I'll study it in more detail.