# Getting image DPI to calculate printing size in Rust

Tags: image-processing, rust

I've recently started to build small app with Tauri. The task is to parse all image files in user selected folder and display in table information about the image (name, width in meters, height in meters, area in sq. m). The issue I'm facing is that I can't reliably get DPI info from images, which is required to convert images dimension from pixels to meters units.

I have previously written this functionality in Python and it works. Here is the code -

```py
from PIL import Image
def calculate_area_from_file(file_path):

        # Open image and get dimensions in pixels
        image = Image.open(file_path)
        width, height = image.size

        # Extract DPI and convert to meters (default to 300 DPI if not available)
        dpi = image.info.get('dpi', (300, 300))[0]
        width_m = width / dpi * 0.0254
        height_m = height / dpi * 0.0254

        # Calculate area
        area_m2 = width_m * height_m

        return area_m2, f"File: {os.path.basename(file_path)}, Height: {height_m:.2f} m, Width: {width_m:.2f} m, " \
                        f"Area: {area_m2:.2f} m²"
```

I've tried using kamadak-exif to get XResolution tag, but it doesn't work with PNG format and fails to retrieve DPI in the images where Python code succeeds.

Comment: This depends on the image type. If you only want to support `PNG` I could provide an answer for that.

Comment: Here is a link to frankenapps post in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76176197/13480381